# Ensure SSH is responsive under heavy load?

Tags: ssh

I've got a lot of Linux servers which easily become unresponsive over SSH under heavy load. Under heavy IO, swapping, CPU usage, etc, SSH connection often time out failing to connect. Its difficult to get console access to these machines, so I need SSH to be reliable.

Can anyone recommend a way of doing this, any options go change? Is simply re-niceing SSHD to -20 going to help much?

Comment: In my opinion, setting the nice level is about all you can do. When servers get extremely loaded, there is going to be degradation of ssh service. What you can do is try and do is prevent your load from getting too high in the first place.

Comment: Are you able to determine why the ssh session is unresponsive? You could consider implementing an Out of Band management network to ensure connectivity under load. It may not resolve your issue but worth thinking about if you have a large enough environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a remote console such as IPMI or a KVM over IP solution will come in handy. This way, even if the server is locked up tight you should still be able to log into the console.

I have however seen cases where even the console is unresponsive...in those cases you should be evaluation server resources well before its workload overwhelms the kernel and it stops working altogether.